# In-App Billing test on the second Android device

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I am trying to test In-App Billing  for non-consumable. For the first time I did test on Nox emulator and the purchase process was completed successfully. But then for the second time I did test on real phone and I found that the product (non-consumable) has already been purchased.

Again I did all the above steps first on the real phone and second on the Nox emulator and this time : 
the purchase process was successfully on the phone, and has already been purchased on the emulator.

Why for second time the purchase is already done?

What code should I add to my project?

Comment: That's right. Both purchases are made with one google account.

Answer (score 0):

Purchases are linked to the google account, not to the device, and non-consumable items can be bought only once, if you use the same account in both devices then what you described is the expected behavior.

If you want to purchase the item again with the same account you should consume it first.